# Autofixture: How to express the following code declaratively?

Tags: c#, xunit, autofixture

I am having trouble expressing the following code in a declarative fashion:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(@"-o=C:\Temp\someFile -p=1")]
[InlineData(@"-p=1 -o=C:\Temp\someFile")]
public void ParseMissingParameterShouldReturnCorrectResult(
    string argsString
)
{
    .....
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Register<IFoo>(fixture.Create<Foo>);
    fixture.Register<IBar>(fixture.Create<Bar>);

    var sut = fixture.Create<SomeClass>();
    .....
}
```

In my production code, I've got something like:

```
new SomeClass(new Foo(new Bar))
```

with the constructor of SomeClass being defined as:

```
public SomeClass(IFoo foo)
```

TIA,

David

EDIT:

SomeClass looks like

```
public class SomeClass : IQux
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;

    public SomeClass(IFoo foo)
    {       
        _foo= foo;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the [SUT](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html) (which is the `SomeClass` type) as a parameter on the test method:

```
[Theory]
[InlineAutoMockData(@"-o=C:\Temp\someFile -p=1")]
[InlineAutoMockData(@"-p=1 -o=C:\Temp\someFile")]
public void ParseMissingParameterShouldReturnCorrectResult(
    string argsString,
    SomeClass sut)
{
}
```

An easy way to create the `[InlineAutoMockData]` attribute is:

```
internal class InlineAutoMockDataAttribute : CompositeDataAttribute
{
    internal InlineAutoMockDataAttribute (params object[] values)
        : base(
            new InlineDataAttribute(values),
            new AutoDataAttribute(
                new Fixture().Customize(
                    new CompositeCustomization(
                        new AutoMoqCustomization()))))
    {
    }
}
```

---

**Note**:

If you also need to setup expectations on the `IFoo` or `IBar` mocked instances you can *freeze* them so that the same `Frozen` instances are passed in the `SomeClass` instance:

```
[Theory]
[InlineAutoMockData(@"-o=C:\Temp\someFile -p=1")]
[InlineAutoMockData(@"-p=1 -o=C:\Temp\someFile")]
public void ParseMissingParameterShouldReturnCorrectResult2(
    string argsString,
    [Frozen]Mock<IFoo> mock,
    [Frozen]Mock<IBar> stub,
    SomeClass sut)
{
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working in my case as I get the following exception:`Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException: AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from nameSpace.IFoo, most likely because it has no public constructor, is an abstract or non-public type.`. The only difference is that I'm using FakeItEasy.

Comment: If you are using FakeItEasy, just replace the `AutoMoqCustomization` with the `AutoFakeItEasyCustomization`. Also note that the examples provided use `InlineAutoMockData` (not the built-in `InlineData` or the `InlineAutoData`).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explicitly say it but I did use `AutoFakeItEasyCustomization` :). But I still get the error above.

Comment: That's great. How does the `SomeClass` looks like?

Comment: I've updated the original question :). If you want I can provide access to the source code but you'll have to provide me with an email. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: FWIW, I created a Gist with the code I inferred from the original question https://gist.github.com/moodmosaic/5434611 Both test pass..

Comment: My apologies, I had mistyped `InlineAutoDataAttribute` instead of `InlineDataAttribute` and your code does indeed work.